# Unable to use types between multiple Rust libraries via Python bindings created with PyO3

Tags: python-3.x, rust, pyo3

I am writing a Rust project with several libraries. Some of the libraries export types that are consumed by other libraries in the workspace. In addition to the Rust crates, I would also like to expose some of the libraries to Python, using the [`pyo3` crate](https://pyo3.rs/v0.11.0/) to generate Python bindings, and here is where I'm running into trouble.

The issue is as follows.

Suppose we have two Rust library crates, `producer`, and `consumer`. In `producer`, we have a simple type, `MyClass` that is publicly available, and is made part of a Python module. In the `consumer` crate, I have a few functions that accept objects of type `MyClass`, and perform some operations on them. Those functions are available in Rust, and also bound into a second Python module.

I can create objects of `MyClass` in both Python and Rust. I can correctly call the functions in Rust code (e.g., from another application) which accept objects of `MyClass`. But I cannot call the functions in the `consumer` module *from Python* which accept objects of type `MyClass`. In other words, while I can create objects of type `MyClass` in Rust or Python and use them in the Rust `consumer` crate, *I cannot pass the object from the `producer` Python module to the `consumer` Python module*. Doing so generates a `TypeError`, despite the object advertising itself as having type `MyClass`. Why?

**EDIT:** Please see the bottom of the question for further investigation.

I have made an MCVE, which is available from [GitHub here](https://github.com/bnaecker/pyo3-typecheck). The Rust and Python code is also contained below.

#### Reproducing:

After cloning the repo, you can generate the output I get with:

```sh
$ cargo build
$ python3 runme.py
```

You should see:

```sh
Object is of type: <class 'MyClass'>
isinstance(obj, MyClass): true
Could not convert object! PyErr { type: Py(0x10d79e5b0, PhantomData) }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runme.py", line 32, in <module>
    consumer.print_data(obj)
TypeError
```

#### Platform details:

- macOS 10.14.6
- cargo 1.44.0 (05d080faa 2020-05-06)
- rustc 1.44.0 (49cae5576 2020-06-01)
- Python 3.7.7
- pyo3 v0.11.1

#### Code:

```rust
/// producer.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct MyClass {
    data: u64,
}

#[pymethods]
impl MyClass {
    #[new]
    fn new(data: u64) -> Self {
        MyClass { data }
    }

    pub fn get_data(&self) -> u64 {
        self.data
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn producer(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<MyClass>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
/// consumer.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;

use producer::MyClass;

#[pyfunction]
fn print_data(cls: &MyClass) {
    println!("{}", cls.get_data());
}

#[pyfunction]
fn convert_to_myclass(obj: &PyAny) -> PyResult<()> {
    match obj.extract::<MyClass>() {
        Ok(_) => println!("Converted to MyClass successfully"),
        Err(err) => println!("Could not convert object! {:?}", err),
    }
    Ok(())
}

#[pyfunction]
fn print_type_info(obj: &PyAny) {
    let typ = obj.get_type();
    println!("Object is of type: {}", typ);
    println!("isinstance(obj, MyClass): {}", typ.is_instance(obj).unwrap());
}

#[pymodule]
fn consumer(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(print_data))?;
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(print_type_info))?;
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(convert_to_myclass))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This small Python script demonstrates the issue. The first function is to ensure that the built crates can be imported by the script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""runme.py
MCVE showing showing type weirdness in Python/PyO3.
(C) 2020 Benjamin Naecker
"""

import os
import platform


def link_libraries():
    names = ("libproducer", "libconsumer")
    lib_extension = ".so" if platform.system() == "Linux" else ".dylib"
    base_path = "./target/debug/"
    for name in names:
        source = os.path.join(base_path, f"{name}{lib_extension}")
        new_name = name.replace("lib", "")
        dest = f"./{new_name}.so"
        if os.path.exists(dest):
            os.remove(dest)
        os.symlink(source, dest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    link_libraries()
    import producer
    import consumer

    obj = producer.MyClass(10)
    consumer.print_type_info(obj)
    consumer.convert_to_myclass(obj)
    consumer.print_data(obj)
```

#### Update:

I have been digging more into this, and I'm beginning to suspect that the issue somehow arises from the way Rust libraries are built. I'm familiar with libraries in general, but not so much with any Rust-specifics. It seems though that Rust encodes a hash into every mangled symbol name. My current guess is that these hashes are slightly different between the `consumer` shared library and the `producer`, so that despite the type of `MyClass` having the same textual representation, the actual type expected in the `consumer` functions is slightly different.

Here are some details to make this concrete. Listing the symbols in each crate and then demangling them with [`rustfilt`](https://github.com/luser/rustfilt) shows:

```sh
$ nm producer.so | grep -e "MyClass.*type_object" | rustfilt -h
0000000000085fa8 d _<producer::MyClass as pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo>::type_object_raw::TYPE_OBJECT::h215179c585bab4ba
0000000000021810 t _<producer::MyClass as pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo>::type_object_raw::h115c96004643f7df
$ nm consumer.so | grep -e "MyClass.*type_object" | rustfilt -h
0000000000091430 d _<producer::MyClass as pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo>::type_object_raw::TYPE_OBJECT::h215179c585bab4ba
0000000000004260 t _<producer::MyClass as pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo>::type_object_raw::h0e4c5c91a2345444
0000000000027a70 t _<producer::MyClass as pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo>::type_object_raw::h115c96004643f7df
```

You can see that there is one additional `type_obect_raw` in the symbols for the `consumer` crate. I'm not sure how to verify this, but I suspect that this is the type information used to convert the object passed to the function that fails in the `consumer` crate. This type object, though having the same name, must differ in some way, since the hash is different.

Looking at the [`pyo3` docs](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.11.1/pyo3/type_object/trait.PyTypeInfo.html#tymethod.type_object_raw), the method `type_object_raw` is used to return the actual `PyTypeObject` that represents the type of an object. It seems plausible to me that when constructing an instance of `MyClass` from the `producer` module, the type object is returned from the symbol `type_object_raw::h115c96004643f7df`. But when the functions like `consumer::print_data` try to convert the passed instance of `MyClass`, they use the symbol `type_object_raw::h0e4c5c91a2345444` to get the type of the object. Presumably these are different.

So now my question is, why are there two different symbols for returning the type of an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: I tried creating one parent module with both producer and consumer as submodules within a single library, and that made everything work (as described [here](https://pyo3.rs/master/module.html#modules-as-objects)). Would that be a workable solution? It supports the theory that the `MyClass` is somehow different in each library.

Comment: @myrtlecat Yep, that's what I've been doing in the meantime. It's not exactly the arrangement I'd like, but it's allowed me to make progress on other parts of the project. I'm still interested in understanding _why_ the two crates have different "versions" of `MyClass`. There's got to be some detail of how Rust libraries are built that require this, and I'd love to understand what it is

Comment: Is the problem occurring because `MyClass::type_object_raw(py)` uses a lazy static?

Comment: @myrtlecat Where do you see a lazy static? Somewhere in the PyO3 source? I can't seem to find anything related to the `type_object_raw` method.

Comment: It's a bit hard to find since it is generated by a macro. I used the `cargo expand` command (needs installation: `cargo install cargo-expand`) to see what `#[pyclass]` does to `MyClass` in `producer/src/lib.rs`.

Comment: I believe it comes from [here](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/b2e7acd1815c6a014cc64d38346b7d4117ce145a/pyo3-derive-backend/src/pyclass.rs#L412)

Comment: @myrtlecat I'm not really sure I understand the internals of that `LazyStaticType` (see [here](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.11.1/src/pyo3/type_object.rs.html#149)), but nothing seems obviously "library-specific" about that to me. Why would the `TYPE_OBJECT` in the implementation you linked above be different in the two libraries? How does it being a `LazyStaticType` make it so?

Comment: @myrtlecat By the way, I believe I printed at some point the actual `PyTypeObject` for the two versions of `MyClass`. As far as I could tell, they were identical, but that may deserve a second look.

Comment: The type-checking ultimately checks that the **raw pointers** to the types are equal, i.e. that the same are at the same address, not that their contents are the same. Try printing `MyClass::type_object_raw` from each crate and you will see that they are different.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, which will generate two symbols with different type info for same pyclass. In my case, I make the pyclass module a standalone crate, and mark it as `dylib` to make sure it's only compiled once, then reference it from other crates. This will make sure your pyclass is only compiled ONCE.

Due to rust's compilation model which will compile same library multiple times in different translation unit, everytime compilation happens on pyclass, it will generate a different python type (with same name), and it became really confusing when you have pyo3 complaining about your PyABC object can't convert to PyABC object!

Comment: would other users (from outside of my workspace) be able to use this `dylib` to create objext compatible with my own lib? Or would the `dylib` compile on their side to something which won't be recognised by my lib?